# Android - Testing an intent that launches unknown external activity

Tags: android, android-intent, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-testing

I have an activity that launches an external activity on button click. The external activity is launched based on action and the activity name and its package name are unknown. I try to mock this intent using Espresso but that does not work and the test fails.

**MyActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLaunchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launch_button);
    mLaunchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Launch button clicked.");
                startActivity(new Intent("action_string"));
            }
        });
}
```

**MyActivityTest.java**

```
@Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> mIntentRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(MyActivity.class);
@Test
    public void testActivity() {
        onView(withId(R.id.launch_button)).perform(click());
        intended(hasAction("action_string"));
    }
```

**Error**

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 391, 715 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.domain.myapp:id/launch_button'.
.
.
.
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=action_string (has extras) }
.
.
.
```